# GoogleMaps / Places Invalid API Key error Swift 3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, swift3

UPDATED:

I setup a project for GoogleMaps + GooglePlaces and have the API's imported. My issue is I constantly get Invalid API key error in my code. I have checked my API with a tutorial app off of Google and the API key is valid. Either my code to check the validity of said api key is bad, or I have not finished setting up the API's. In the settings on my google dashboard, does renaming my api key do anything or is that just superficial?

Selecting the Cell Starts the call to the url / api

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! Cell
    var id: String = String()
    var image: String = String()

    if (placeFiltered) {
        id = String(filteredPlaces[indexPath.row].components(separatedBy: ":").first!)
    } else {
        id = String(indexPath.row)
    }

    image = "Place Icon-" + id + " Selected"
    cell.placeIcon.image = UIImage(named: image)

    var placeType: String = String()

    if (placeFiltered) {
        placeType = String(filteredPlaces[indexPath.row].components(separatedBy: ":").last!)
    } else {
        placeType = String(Google.placeTypes[indexPath.row].components(separatedBy: ":").last!)
    }

    let type = (placeType.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")).lowercased()
    let location = String(latitude) + "," + String(longitude)

    GoogleClient.sharedInstance().fetchNearbyPlaces(of: type, for: location) { (success, error) in

        GCDBlakBox {

            self.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            self.searchBarCancelButtonClicked(self.searchBar)

            if success {

                self.dropAllData() { (success, error) in
                    if success {

                        self.saveType(placeType: placeType) { (result) in
                            if (result != nil) {

                                self.savePlace(result!) { (result) in
                                    if (result != nil) {

                                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toPlaceTabBarController", sender: placeType)
                                    } else {
                                        self.displayError("Error saving search result")
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                self.displayError("Error saving search result")
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.displayError(error)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                var errorMessage: String = error!

                if (errorMessage == Google.ResponseValues.zeroResults) {
                    if (self.appDelegate.searchNearby) {
                        errorMessage = "There is no " + (placeType).lowercased() + " nearby within 30 miles"
                    } else {
                        errorMessage = "There is no " + (placeType).lowercased() + " nearby. Please increase the radius and search again"
                    }
                }

                self.displayError(errorMessage)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then this function is called

```
func fetchNearbyPlaces(of type: String, for location: String, completionHandlerForFetchPlaces: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ error: String?) -> Void) {

        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

        var parameters: [String:Any] = [
            Google.ParameterKeys.type: type,
            Google.ParameterKeys.location: location,
            Google.ParameterKeys.key: Google.apiKey
        ]

        let searchNearby = appDelegate.searchNearby
        let searchRadius = appDelegate.searchRadius

        if (searchNearby) {
            parameters[Google.ParameterKeys.rankby] = Google.ParameterValues.distance
        } else {
            parameters[Google.ParameterKeys.rankby] = Google.ParameterValues.prominence
            parameters[Google.ParameterKeys.radius] = searchRadius
        }

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: urlFrom(parameters, withPathExtension: Google.URL.output))

        let _ = taskForData(request) { (success, error, result) in

            guard (error == nil) else {
                completionHandlerForFetchPlaces(false, error)
                return
            }

            if success {

                guard let status = result?[Google.ResponseKeys.status] as? String else {
                    completionHandlerForFetchPlaces(false, "Place search failed")
                    return
                }

                if (status == Google.ResponseValues.ok) {
                    if (self.appDelegate.googlePlaces.count != 0) {
                        self.appDelegate.googlePlaces.removeAll()
                    }

                    let results = result?[Google.ResponseKeys.results] as! Array<NSDictionary>
                    self.appDelegate.googlePlaces = GooglePlaces.allPlacesFrom(results)
                    completionHandlerForFetchPlaces(true, nil)
                } else if (status == Google.ResponseValues.zeroResults) {
                    completionHandlerForFetchPlaces(false, status)
                } else if (status == Google.ResponseValues.overQueryLimit) {
                    completionHandlerForFetchPlaces(false, "Daily search limit exceeded. Try again tomorrow")
                } else if (status == Google.ResponseValues.requestDenied) {
                    completionHandlerForFetchPlaces(false, "Request denied. Invalid API key") // HERE IS WHERE I GET MY ERROR !!!!!!! 
                } else if (status == Google.ResponseValues.invalidRequest) {
                    completionHandlerForFetchPlaces(false, "Invalid request")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GIT: 
https://github.com/whitesoxmike/Tourist-Error.git

UPDATE: I made a simplified verifiable project

Comment: I fixed the collection cells to show demo images not for final app. However, I am still getting invalid API key. To even get the app started, It checks the api key and checks again later after a collection cell is touched. Thats when I get the error.

Comment: Do not upload your whole project to GitHub. Rather create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include that in your question.

Comment: Okay, I just did that.

Comment: Did you even look at the page I linked or read my comment? Do not make a full Xcode project, include the problematic code __in the question itself__.

Comment: I did read your reply and tried to make a git thats as simple as can be. Whats confusing me is the api key works in other apps that make a similar call, tapping on a cell, calling a function, etc. as well as working on a simple amp / pin app ( google tutorial app ), And as I step through the code, I get no errors except for the invalid api key. So as a newbie, I am a little lost and Google's not helping.